# In PromQL, how to specify resolution with <agg>_over_time() and prevent interpolation

Tags: interpolation, resolution, promql

I need to write a query that looks for sudden drops in traffic, so I am attempting to get the current 10 minutes and compare it to the previous few 10 minute buckets.

Here I get 6 values of total traffic for each 10 minutes over past 1 hour.  Seems easy enough:

```
sum(
  increase(
    istio_requests_total{destination_workload="service-v1", reporter="source"}[10m:10m]
  )
)
```

This yields the following result.  Notice I only get 6 values with no interpolation, exactly what I want.

```
Time                      Value
2023-08-25 14:50:00           5
2023-08-25 15:00:00           7
2023-08-25 15:10:00           8
2023-08-25 15:20:00           6
2023-08-25 15:30:00           9
2023-08-25 15:40:00           5
```

To get the current 10 minutes only, I tried:

```
last_over_time(
  sum(
    increase(
      istio_requests_total{destination_workload="service-v1", reporter="source"}[10m:10m]
    )
  )[10m:10m]
)
```

But bizarrely, the interpolation comes back and I get the default interval of 5s:

```
Time                      Value
2023-08-25 14:47:10           5
2023-08-25 14:47:15           5
2023-08-25 14:47:20           5
[ ... as many 5 seconds as there are in an hour ]
```

I am expecting no interpolation like the first example and just 1 value:

```
Time                      Value
2023-08-25 15:40:00           5
```

The reason I cannot just change the overall time frame to just 10 minutes is because I need those other values to get the avg, min, and max of all other buckets except the first to build the baseline.  Then I can compare the current 10 minute bucket with the average of each 10 minute bucket of the past hour to detect sudden changes, and to make sure if the current 10 min is lower than the minimum 10 minute value so the alert will self-throttle unless it gets worse.

This is not going in Grafana so any Grafana solutions unfortunately won't work.

How Can i get <agg>_over_time() functions to honor the specified resolution of 10m and not interpolate the value throughout every 5s interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a misconception of resolution used in range selectors. If is used to return range vector it's in fact [behave like you expect](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=up%5B1m%3A20s%5D&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h), but it's rare case, and this behavior doesn't extend to result of functions using range vectors as input.

To get only one result per every 10 minutes you need to pass appropriate [`step` parameter](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries) to your request (in this case it will be `step=10m`).

`increase(something [10m:10m])` generally isn't expected to produce anything, because `increase` needs at least 2 points to calculate result. On the other hand something like `increase(something [10m:5m])` is expected to produce result for every step. So the fact that you got 6 points with your initial query is a lucky coincidence.

Here is [demo](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=sum(increase(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22user%22%7D%5B10m%5D))&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g1.expr=sum(increase(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22user%22%7D%5B10m%3A5m%5D))&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=1h&g2.expr=sum(increase(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22user%22%7D%5B10m%5D))&g2.tab=0&g2.stacked=0&g2.range_input=1h&g2.step_input=600&g3.expr=sum(increase(node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22user%22%7D%5B10m%3A10m%5D))&g3.tab=1&g3.stacked=0&g3.range_input=1h) of different approaches. Notice that first two graphs have value every 14 seconds (default value). And the third one - only once every 600 seconds. The last one doesn't produce anything (maybe if you are lucky and press "execute" in exactly round 10m time it will? I'm not sure on that).

---

I believe you also have a wrong conception of `last_over_time`. It is used to "stretch" last seen value over periods of absence. Demo of what it does [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22user%22%7D%20and%20on()%20minute()%3E15%3C45&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=2h&g1.expr=last_over_time((node_cpu_seconds_total%7Bmode%3D%22user%22%7D%20and%20on()%20minute()%3E15%3C45)%5B1h%3A%5D)&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=2h).

I'm not sure what you trying to do in your case, as it's not clear your how you intend to use in later, but generally to receive last value (relatively passed `time` parameter, you don't need to do anything special: just pass your query. (Or maybe you wanted to use something like [`@end()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#modifier)?)

---

Regarding

> compare the current 10 minute bucket with the average of each 10 minute bucket of the past hour to detect sudden changes, and to make sure if the current 10 min is lower than the minimum 10 minute value

If all you want to find if increase of counter over current 10 minutes are lower than increases over 5 previous 10 minutes windows, you can simply use following query:

```
increase(my_counter[10m])
 < increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 10m
 < increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 20m
 < increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 30m
 < increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 40m
 < increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 50m
```

EDIT: to accommodate rule "return value if current 10 minutes increase is less then 50% of average increase over previous 50 minutes" you can use query like

```
increase(my_counter[10m]) < increase(my_counter[50m] offset 10m) / 5 * 0.5
```

Here:

- `increase(my_counter[10m])` - increase over "current" 10 minutes,
- `increase(my_counter[50m] offset 10m)` - increase over previous 50 minutes. Equivalent to `increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 10m + increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 20m + increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 30m + increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 40m + increase(my_counter[10m]) offset 50m`,
- `/ 5` since right-hand side is 5 times longer - divide by 5 to equate time windows,
- `* 0.5` - your threshold of 50%.

Comment: The time window is 60 minutes as stated, so the 10m here is why increase() produces output.  I don't think this is a lucky coincidence that it produces 6 values as there are 6 10 minute windows in an hour.  What may appear coincidental is that it also produces no interpolation which is I want.  Changing the resolution barely will bring them all back.

Unfortunately, the solution only handles one of my conditions, to be less than the minimum, but the most important condition is getting the average because I need to detect sudden drops in overall volume, like a 50% drop compared to baseline.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the demos.  last_over_time did not work as I expect as you say, but it does get me the same answer as I need, so I think it is still good.

Comment: What I intend to do is take the latest value (latest 10m bucket), and if less than 50% of the average of the rest of the 10m buckets, then alert.  the idea is to detect sudden drops in volume.  If there is another way to detect sudden changes (drops in volume, increases in failure rate), then that will work too.

Comment: @FigureOfCode, last part of my answer is merely a suggestion to consider using promql to check drop instead of "manual" processing. And since in was not clear what kind of threshold you expect to use, it was something of a guess. To clarify, you want "alert" if previous 50 minutes all averaged to 10, and current one to something less than 5?

Comment: Thanks, and yes that is a good way to achieve that condition.  Your example is also correct.  if previous five 10-minutes averaged to 10 units of traffic, and current 10 min was only 5, I would want an alert.

Comment: @FigureOfCode, added query for your rule to the answer.

Comment: thanks, i checked out the query.  When manually getting the average from a particular time of day, i got 7.5, but the query gives 8.2.  This example is off by about 10%.  Do you know why this would be?

Comment: @FigureOfCode, no, I don't know. You need to investigate values returned by parts of queries and compare with you manual results.

Comment: I think it has to do with the query language's problems attempting to produce exact values.  I have had nothing but problems with this language.  It can only produce approximations and is always off by a little bit.  Ill accept this answer because I don't think there could be a better one.  thanks for you help.

Comment: @FigureOfCode, ah, yeah, `increase` is using rate internally and is prone to some interpolation error. If you'll search here you'll hind a bunch of questions on related topic.