# Prometheus query alert if average memory/CPU utilization is trending up

Tags: kubernetes, alert, promql, prometheus-alertmanager, thanos

​​The actual requirement is if CPU/memory increases​(trending up) continuously due to a memory leak and finally one day container may blast and recreate right due to memory/CPU exhausted
​Before blasting the container user should monitor the status by the alerts

1.increasing continuously without decreasing for period of time --> **Alert should raise**
2.increasing and decreasing for period of time --> **Alert should not raise**

Both points should include in single expression in the Prometheus rule​ for both CPU/Memory in single expression

**My goal is to monitor container memory/cpu for a continuous increase over time and alert only if there are no decreases within a specified period**

Comment: Please add query you have used for graph from the screenshot to the question (as text!). Also, please share what you tried, and how it failed your expectations.

Comment: **Memory**
          `expr: avg_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes{container!="", pod!=""}[5m]) > avg_over_time(container_memory_usage_bytes{container!="", pod!=""}[10m])
          for: 5m`


**CPU**
          `expr: |
            avg_over_time(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="", pod!=""}[1d]) >
            1.1 * avg_over_time(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="", pod!=""}[7d])
          for: 5m`

I wrote this expression for my requirement but not sure correct or not

Comment: Please [edit] your queries into your question. Comments are considered ephemeral and frequently and easily deleted. All the information related to question should be a part of question. Plus, post allows a proper formatting.

Comment: Regarding CPU: it's incorrect. You see, your metric name is ended in the `_total`. This means it's a counter. `avg_over_time` for counter doesn't make much sense.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76982045/21363224)(specifically EDIT there) for the CPU part. You need `increase(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="", pod!=""}[1d]) > increase(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!="", pod!=""}[6d] offset 1d) /6 * 1.1`

Comment: @markalex Any help on this? modified my queries please check